# component not re-rendering once user is set

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm using Context to keep track of the user.

I've created the context:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export function UserProvider(props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I've wrapped my app with the UserProvider. I have a component called Appbar, that displays whether a user logged in or not. If the user is logged in, it should show a signout button and if user isn't logged in, it should show a signin button.

The Appbar component:

```
export default function Appbar(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);

    return (
        <AppBar className={classes.appbar} color="primary" position="static">
        <Toolbar className={classes.tab}>
        <Typography variant="h6">
            Duncc Blogs
            </Typography>
                {user ? <Button color="inherit" onClick={async () => {
                    const googleUser = signOut;
                    setUser(googleUser);
                }}>Logout</Button> : <Button color="inherit" onClick={async () => {
                        const googleUser = await signIn;
                        setUser(googleUser);
                    }} className="button">Login</Button>}
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    )
}
```

The problem is, when the user has successfully signed in, I want my Appbar component to re-render, so the signout button is visible. But this doesn't happen.

Can someone tell me why? Am I not using the Context API properly?

Comment: What is `const googleUser = signOut` supposed to do?

Comment: check if `googleUser` is a truthy value, what is `signIn`? should that be `signIn()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out setUser() was being called before the user data was fetched, resulting in user being null, regardless of whether the user was signed in or not.

I simply changed it to:

```
{user ? <Button color="inherit" onClick={async () => {
                    signOut().then((value) => {
                        setUser(value);
                    })
                }}>Logout</Button> : <Button color="inherit" onClick={async () => {
                        signIn().then((value)=>{
                            setUser(value)
                        })
                    }} className="button">Login</Button>}
```

Answer (score 0):

`signIn` and `signOut` are probably functions that return the user or null. You are not calling the functions, you are just assigning them right now.

```
const updateUser = async actionType => {
    try {
        if(actionType === "signOut") {
            const googleUser = signOut();
            setUser(googleUser);
        }
        else if(actionType == "signIn"){
            ​const googleUser = await signIn();
       ​     setUser(googleUser);
        } 
    }
    catch(error){...}
}
...
{user ? 
    <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => updateUser("signOut")}>
        Logout
    </Button> : 
    <Button color="inherit" onClick={() => updateUser("signIn")} className="button">
        Login
    </Button>
}
```

Comment: your ans is also incomplete 

try to wrap with try and catch if you are dealing with async await

Comment: You're right about signIn and signOut being functions that return user or null. But they have been called. I get the user details once I click on signIn. I'm pretty sure I'm not using the Context API properly.

Comment: Where have they been called? Because in your code they havent